# create MySQL View with categories table

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

i have a bit of a problem, i have two MySQL tables namely products and categories. The categories table has an id as the primary key and name of the category. The category id is a foreign key in the products table. I want to create a view, but i don't want the view to contain the id as the category,instead i want the category name to be shown in the view. I have tried every kind of JOIN but I'm still not getting the required result. What am i doing wrong? here is my latest join. Which is pretty much the closest to what i want.

`SELECT c.title as title,ct.name as category, c.picture as picture
FROM companies c left join categories ct on ct.id=c.category`

I have successfully gotten the title and picture, but the category remains null.

Comment: Your left join as posted should work correctly provided the condition `ct.id = c.category` is true. Can you post a small sample of rows from both of those tables?  The null category indicates a non match in the join's `ON` clause, but if it's a proper foreign key it should be working.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and the results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.. Michael turns out that you were right , I mixed up the tables  when performing the insert via my web interface so there wasn't a match. Thanks a lot!